# Like/Dislike plugin crawler problem

Tags: plugins, php

I'm making new plugin where users can vote like/dislike my posts. But i have a problem with this plugin. Crawler bots can vote, and i don't know how to prevent it.

Vote links have no follow, but i detect crawaler IPS that they click on Like/Dislike.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to send values to the server, use form elements, eg. `button` or `<input type=submit>`.

Comment: How is this a wordpress specific problem? bots will crawl links, that is what they are for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your definition of a vote as any access to a specific url. Your definition should include both an access and some not trivial info a bot will not have, for example an authentication cookie (i.e., the user has to be logged-in).